# Turning Left Over Broth From a Roast Into a Soup Or Stew

Tags: soup, roast, broth

Two nights ago, I made a roast. Not wanting to waste anything I kept most of the left over beef broth (about 3-4 cups).

My current idea is to turn this beef broth into a soup or a stew. Here's what I was thinking:

1. Skim the fat chucks off the top of the broth (left there by the roast)
2. For a stew I would add in carrots, celery, onions, garlic, and use a potato to naturally thicken the broth as it cooks.
3. For a soup, I would probably just add the vegetables mentioned above minus the potato and then thicken a bit with some cornstarch.

Is this the best way to go about it? Is this a good use of the left over broth?

Comment: You have 3-4 cups of juices left after a roast? How big was the roast?!

Comment: We cooked it in a slow cooker and added about 2.5 cups of beef broth to the slow cooker before turning on the pressure. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The broth can be used for pretty much any soup...if the soups says to add in stock, use the broth instead.

I use broth from ham for making lentil soup, and from a roast use it in pretty much any kind of soup!

Sounds tasty :)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

Cook a risotto with it (pour the broth slowly to the rice while cooking and stirring continuously)

Answer (score 2):

You could use it as the broth base to make a traditional minestrone. Search the web for "minestrone beef broth" and you'll find plenty of recipes.

Answer (score 2):

If yours comes out like my neighbors (she uses a *huge* roaster that'd probably fit a small turkey for doing her roast), you could do a few things:

1. turn it into a gravy for the roast.  (of course, her roast comes out so moist, it doesn't need it, but it still goes great over the mashe potatos.).
2. use it in place of most anything that can use broth (but not stock; it's often too watery, without the necessary gelatin to get the same mouthfeel as stock, as it wasn't made with bones).  However, as it's typically cloudier (I think she throws in a can of cream of mushroom soup, so this might not be true in all cases), I'd stick with stews and other things where you're not trying for a clear final product, so you don't have to bother trying to strain it (if it's even possible).

Answer (score 2):

If I have good beef broth I'd make French Onion soup which needs a very meaty stock.  Its easy to make - just make sure to really sweat the onions down - this will make or break the soup.